# Removing closing table tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove a closing tag after I prepend some html. It adds a closing tag even though I specify no closing tag. Why is this?

At first I have my variable.

```
var tableCode = '<table class=prodDescTable border=1 cellSpacing=0>';
```

I want to add that code before some table rows and I get the html below.

```
<table class="prodDescTable" border="1" cellspacing="0"></table> <tbody> <tr> <th style="BORDER-LEFT: 0px">Product Code Photo</th> <th>Specs</th>
```

It automatically adds the closing table tag when I prepend my html. How would I remove the closing table tag and put it on the end?

EDIT:

Here is my prepend code that I was using

```
$(table).prepend(tableCode);
```

Comment: Can you give more details this is a bit un clear

Comment: What's your code for adding the html?

Comment: jQuery will create a new node, which will include the closing tag (a valid node). Post up your JS code too

Comment: Ditto what @NetaMeta said.  How are you prepending text? What is "it" that adds thing?   Certainly the browser will correct your input to legitimate HTML.

Comment: It sounds like you need `wrap()` or `wrapAll()` instead

Comment: Why would you want to prepend a beginning table tag to a table that already has a beginning table tag?

Comment: The second example has code that is bad. You can see there is a starting table tag and an ending. I am trying to insert an ending tag after everything.

Comment: Are you trying to add a table inbetween rows?, in that case you need to append the table to the row above. or prepend the row below not the table itself.

Comment: Where do you prepending it ? Provide some code... Lets do it.

Comment: I am trying to add a starting table tag to the beginning and an ending table tag at the conclusion.

Comment: If the `table` element already exists, just select it, and use the relevant methods to add the desired attributes (`.addClass('prodDescTable')` etc.)

Comment: Are you dynamically creating the whole table or something? you need to show more code as with out it this just seems like you are trying to add a beginning tag to an element that already has one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't let you prepend "html". It lets you prepend DOM nodes, it just happens to have an API that lets you create them by passing HTML.

Any HTML you pass it will be turned into complete elements.

You need to work with a node tree, not pieces of HTML.

i.e.

```
var table = jQuery('<table>');
var row = jQuery('<tr>');
var cell = jQuery('<td>');
row.append(cell);
table.append(row);
container.append(table);
```

Alternatively, build all your HTML in a string before appending it.

```
var html = '<table>';
html += '<tr>';
html += '<td>';
html += '</td>';
html += '</tr>';
html += '</table>';
container.append(html);
```

Comment: @wowzuzz You might be able to append the existing rows into the table created on the fly with some JS manipulations.

Comment: Not to mention, the browser will fix most errors and insert missing elements

Comment: My problem here was recognizing my thought process in the first sentence of your reply. I thought prepending could work with strings or html. Only works with dom nodes of course. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to build the table first, then add the completed table to the dom

So you can have

```
var newTable = $("<table>");
var newRow = $("<tr>");
var newCell = $("<td>")
$(newCell).append("<div>Hello World!</div>");
$(newRow).append(newCell);
$(newTable).append(newRow);
```

Then add that table to the dom

Answer (score 0):

Probably You are doing something like this (*this will append a closing `</table>` automatically*) -

```
$('#someDivID').prepend(tableCode);
```

You can insert content into your table like this -

```
var htm = '<tbody> <tr> <th style="BORDER-LEFT: 0px">Product Code Photo</th> <th>Specs</th>';
$('#someDivID').prepend($(tableCode).append(htm));
```